# Error: Xamarin iOS: The post for client build...user on topic xvs/build/...ComputeBundleResourceOutputPathshas been cancelled

Tags: xamarin.ios

Visual Studio for Windows 17.7.6

Xcode 15.0.1

Project not build.

```
16> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error: MessagingException: Message for client build1369217544user on topic xvs/build/17.7.0.223/execute-task/App.IOS/bc08bf4002fComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths canceled
16>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error: OperationCanceledException: The operation was cancelled.
16> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error:
16>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: Unexpected error while executing task 'ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths'.
16>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference does not point to an instance of an object.
16> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: in Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths.RemoveDuulates() in / Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths.cs:line 37
16> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: in Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths.Execute() in / Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths.cs:line 17
16> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd .ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
16>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1146,3): error MSB4018: in Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26. MoveNext()
```

Does not work:

1. Restart MAC
2. Restart PC
3. Remove bin and obj folder under the project folder
4. Clean the project (in Visual Studio)
5. Rebuild

6.Clearing the Mac Build Cache

Comment: The error seems to be occurring in the Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths task. If you have access to the Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks source code, you might want to inspect the relevant lines mentioned in the error (line 37 and line 17) to understand the context of the NullReferenceException. It's possible there may be a bug in the Xamarin tools that requires a workaround or an update.